# Как получить размер экрана в пикселях в android?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, разметка, pixmap

Мне нужно получить ширину и высоту экрана на устройстве, на котором сейчас выполняется приложение. Как мне это сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63885311/3212712

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, благодарю!